# OrderBy / Sort list by secondary value in Flutter / Dart for duplicates

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I sort a list with a secondary value - So the list is first sorted by one value then for duplicates of the first value the list is then sorted by a secondary value? Basically I need the functionality you get in SQL queries using orderby valueOne, valueTwo.

valueOne and valueTwo are both ints.

I can sort by single value using:

```
list.sort((a, b) => a.listValueOne.compareTo(b.ListValueOne));
```